# Upgraded .NET Core projects from v1.0 to v1.1 and facing the following errors

Tags: upgrade, asp.net-core-1.0, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-1.1

I upgraded my .NET Core projects from v1.0 to v1.1 and facing the following errors

***Package Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1).***

***Package Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) / win10-x64***

All the projects in the solution are compiling and says "Rebuild Success" but still these errors shows up in the "Error List".

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Is there a fix ? Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clean, rebuild and restore packages?

Comment: Yes - I did it several times. - Even closed and opened Visual Studio 2017. No luck. :(

Comment: delete `obj` and `bin` folders and run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` from command line. What they say?

Comment: I tried it - No luck. I have added the snapshot.

Comment: Can you take a backup of your project, and then run "Update-Package" from the package manager console. This will upgrade all your projects which you may or may not want, but then you can compare the two nuget package lists to see what was upgraded if it resolved your issue.

Comment: It's exactly the same output as shown below by Nick.

Answer (score 0):

Check your output, I've just tried installing Microsoft.Net.Http into my NetCore1.1 project and got the same. Reading the output for the nuget install I see this:

```
Installing Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29.
Package Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29 supports:
  - monoandroid (MonoAndroid,Version=v0.0)
  - monotouch (MonoTouch,Version=v0.0)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net40+sl4+win8+wp71+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net40+sl4+win8+wp71+wpa81)
  - portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
  - portable-net45+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile111)
  - sl4-wp71 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
Package Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10 supports:
  - monoandroid (MonoAndroid,Version=v0.0)
  - monotouch (MonoTouch,Version=v0.0)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net40+sl4+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net40+sl4+win8)
  - portable-net40+sl4+win8+wp71+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net40+sl4+win8+wp71+wpa81)
  - portable-net40+sl4+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net40+sl4+win8+wp8+wpa81)
  - portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile328)
  - portable-net40+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile5)
  - portable-net40+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net40+win8+wp8+wpa81)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - portable-net45+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile111)
  - portable-net451+win81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile44)
  - portable-net451+win81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile151)
  - portable-win81+wp81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile157)
  - sl4 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0)
  - sl4-wp71 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71)
  - sl5 (Silverlight,Version=v5.0)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Notams.Query'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:03.7728926
========== Finished ==========
```

As you can see, this package does not support .Net Core or .Net Standard yet. Also your `Microsoft.Bcl` dependency comes from `Microsoft.Net.Http` and similarly does not support .Net Standard/Core

Your best bet is to switch to `System.Net.Http` which does support .Net Standard and .Net Core

Comment: I checked my entire solution and our team is using only Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http and not Microsoft.Net.Http. Not sure whether they are equivalent. At the same time, I cannot stop using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http and switch to System.Net.http because there are many calls related to this library. For example, "StatusCodes" is being used everywhere. Looks like I have to wait until there is a better solution. Anyways the code is building and working. It's just that annoying errors listed as shown in snapshot above. :)

Comment: @Adam AspNetCore.Http should be fine as all NetCore packages are build on .Net Standard. Have you checked your other dependencies for the packages you're receiving errors on? The compiler sounds pretty certain you have these dependencies somewhere in the tree.

It definitely seems odd you've started getting this after upgrading from 1.0, assuming it was working before.

Comment: I have 7 projects in this solution. I went into each project and deleted the bin and obj folder contents. Reload the Visual Studio 2017 and did a clean and rebuild all and the same set of errors (above snapshot) shows up. They do not refer to any project in the solution. It's really odd and I am not sure how else I can fix this annoying error message.